# Android Workmanger PeriodicWorkRequest API work only once?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

Am Using **androidx** Work manager API, in Work manager am using **PeriodicWorkRequest** to trigger the Work for every 4 hours. But it works only once after run the application.

**PeriodicWorkRequest Coding:-**

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build();

PeriodicWorkRequestpendingCampaignWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(PendingCampaignWorker.class, 4, TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build();
```

**Work Manger Code to Enqueue the Request:-**

```
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(LATEST_CAMPAIGN_WORK, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, pendingCampaignWork);
```

For testing am change System time Manually to 4 hours after run the application in emulator to trigger the Work.

Is there any issue in my code help me to solve the issue.

**Update:-**

Work Manager is working fine, its not working based on System time as **m.hassan** said in answer section. Am test to trigger the **work** for every 20 minutes, its working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work Manager Not not based on system time. You can make a periodic work request of 15 minutes. This way you can test your code.

here's an example:

My Periodic Work Request:

```
private static final String TAG = "PeriodicWorkTag";
private static final int PERIODIC_WORK_INTERVAL = 15;

public static void schedulePeriodicWork() {
    androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest = new androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(PeriodicWorkRequest.class, PERIODIC_WORK_INTERVAL,
            TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addTag(TAG)
            .build();
    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, periodicWorkRequest);
}

public static void cancelPeriodicWork() {
    WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWorkByTag(TAG);
}
```

My Worker Class:

```
public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "VERBOSE_NOTIFICATION" ;
public PeriodicWorkRequest(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    showNotification(getApplicationContext());
    return Result.SUCCESS;
}

private void showNotification(Context context) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("ddd")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText("ddd"))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "Channel_name";
        String description = "description";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManager.notify(100, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: OneTimeWorkRequest is working but not the PeriodicWorkRequest

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick in my case: Add your app to `IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` list.

```java
@SuppressLint("BatteryLife")
    public void showIgnoreBatteryOpt() {
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "showIgnoreBatteryOpt: NOT ignoring");
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "showIgnoreBatteryOpt: ignoring");
        }

    }
```

Add to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```